# Different expressions of factorization

Tags: recursion, products

*(This question might have incorrect tags)*

I was playing with different expressions of factorization. Here's what I was doing. We all know that

$$\begin{align*}
a^2-b^2&=(a+b)(a-b)\\[5pt]
a-b&=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})\\[5pt]
&=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt[4]{a}+\sqrt[4]{b})(\sqrt[4]{a}-\sqrt[4]{b})\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Now if we continue this process infinitely then we get the formula:

$$a-b=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(a^{2^{-k}}+b^{2^{-k}})$$

and

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a^{2^{-k}}+b^{2^{-k}})=\frac{a-b}{a^{2^{-n}}-b^{2^{-n}}}$$

But if I input this thing on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product+of+%28a%5E2%5E-k%2Bb%5E2%5E-k%29+as+k%3D1+to+%E2%88%9E) I get nothing.

And also if I input [the second expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product+of+%28a%5E2%5E-k%2Bb%5E2%5E-k%29+as+k%3D1+to+n) then I also get nothing.

So, are these formulas correct?

Comment: In the product formula all factors are additions, excepting for the last factor that is a difference. You have missed the last factor.

Comment: One obvious problem with the first formula involving the product operator is that it does not account for the presence of a negative sign between the two terms.

Comment: Also in the last expression the difference factor- the you missed a line above is at exponent $2^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: @Windsoul and an4s. The difference term is dependent on how many times we decide to factor. So if we factor infinitely many times, shouldn't the difference term vanish?

Comment: @Windsoul. Why should the exponent be $2^{-(n+1)}$?

Comment: To account for the difference factor

Comment: @Windsoul. Please. I am extremely confused. It is hard to understand what you saying when we ate talking in the comment section. So please write it clearly in the answer since that is what my question asks for.

Comment: In my previous comment I made a mistake with the exponent, should be n instead of n+1. Please check the answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your expression of the product results from missing the difference factor.

$a-b=(a^{2^{-n}}-b^{2^{-n}})\prod_{k=1}^n {a^{2^{-k}}+b^{2^{-k}}}$

Comment: Since the L.H.S is independent of n, can we take $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of the R.H.S?

Comment: Of course. However, the right side simplifies to the left so if you decide to check the limit you should necessarily obtain the same thing. The difference factor tends to zero, however it always multiplies to a difference of squares until the entire product results in the left side. To conclude: apply the limit if you want but you won’t obtain a different result.